# Why the part question labels are not vertically left aligned in exam class

Tags: vertical-alignment, lists, exam

I'm using `TexLive` 2015 under Windows XP, and using the latest `exam` class. Here is the sample code build by `Xelatex` engine.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{exam}

\begin{document}
\begin{questions}
\question[10] questions
\begin{parts}
\part[2] part one
\part[4] part two
\part[4] part three
\end{parts}
\begin{solution}[10cm]
solution
\end{solution}

\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

The result screen shot see below.
[image: screen shot of the result]

You see that the part (b) and (c) are not vertically aligned. Any ideas? Thanks.

**EDIT:** as Manuel told me that it did aligned at the `)`, so my question is: Is it possible to both aligned at `(` and `)`, only aligned at `)` dose not look quite nice as the screen shot shows. Because `(c)` looks a bit smaller than the `(b)` as shown in the image.

**EDIT2:** I mark egreg's answer as the solution, since I think align on both `(` and `)` is not a good idea, see comments below.

Comment: They are vertically aligned at the *end*, that is, after the `)` in in the item label.

Comment: @Manuel Oh, I do see that, but it looks not quite nice if the `(` is not aligned. Is it possible to aligned at both `(` and `)`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use (perhaps abuse) the `\partshook` command, that's usually empty, in order to modify the definition `\parts` does for `\makelabel`; `\parts` defines `\makelabel` to do `\hss\llap{##1}`, which makes for the label to be right aligned in the reserved space, so we can make it do `\rlap{##1}\hss` (that is, the reverse).

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{exam}

\renewcommand{\partshook}{%
  \renewcommand\makelabel[1]{\rlap{##1}\hss}%
}

\begin{document}
\begin{questions}
\question[10] questions
\begin{parts}
\part[2] part one
\part[4] part two
\part[4] part three
\end{parts}
\begin{solution}[10cm]
solution
\end{solution}

\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, egreg, thanks, from the screen shot of your answer, I still see `(c)` is a little smaller than the `(b)`, so this is still the format I expected. Is it possible to format the label text, I mean add a fixed size box around the "a", "b" and "c", so that I can have both aligned `(` and `)`, thanks.

Comment: follow the method you mentioned, I may find the solution, I just add a line `\renewcommand\partlabel{(\hbox to 10pt{\hfil \thepartno\hfil)}}` inside the `partshook` body, and it looks fine.

Comment: @ollydbg23 I wouldn't do that, but it's your document. `;-)`

Comment: I just looked at the page:[wiki books Latex 2 Nested lists](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/List_Structures#Nested_lists), it looks like the aligned on the `)` is the default way for the `enumerate` environment, so no one has complain this alignment before?

Comment: @ollydbg23 Yes, that's the default for LaTeX lists.

Comment: @ollydbg23 Ask yourself what alignment  is worse if the labels have different number of characters like in  `\item[a] xxx \item[bbb] xxx`.

Comment: OK, I mark egreg's answer as the solution of this question.  It implemented the alignment on the `(`, in-fact, I see alignment on both `(` and `)` is not a good idea.